# Do I need to free C variables in Objective-C code (iOS 6 with ARC)?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

If I implement the following within iPhone code:

```
NSString* soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundFile ofType:@"wav"];
SystemSoundID feedbackSound;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath], &feedbackSound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(feedbackSound);
```

Do I actually have to free "feedbackSound" as it is C code? Will it leak?

I'm using ARC / iOS 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should. The correct method to call is:

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID
```

([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID)).

In general ARC only deals with Objective-C objects. When you deal with lower-level framework (Core Graphics, AudioServices, etc.) many calls will allocate memory "under the hood" for whose disposal you are responsible. On many occasions, you have specific methods to do the deallocation, as you have for doing the allocation.

Answer (score 1):

ARC only manages memory for Objective-C objects. The System Sound Services however is a C interface. You have to manage memory yourself in this case.

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (feedbackSound);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must. ARC applies only to types declared as Objective-C objects. The program in the question will produce a leak.

`malloc` needs `free`. `new` needs `delete`. `CFStringCreate...` needs `CFRelease` -- and so on…